# Trace inequality normal derivative

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

For $v(\Omega) \in W^1_2$ and $\Omega \in C^1$ we have a trace inequality:

$$\Vert v \Vert _{L_2(\partial \Omega)} \leq C_\Omega \Vert v \Vert _{W_2^1},$$

which can be found in many places in the literature.

Is it then true that for a normal derivative we have:

$$\left \Vert\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}\right \Vert _{L_2(\partial \Omega)} \leq C_\Omega \Vert v \Vert_{W_2^2}?$$
I am not able to find a reference for that.

Comment: Just apply the first inequality to $\nabla v$.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo, but as Lorenzo pointed out the answer seems pretty trivial at the moment. So I feel that this is not quite a research-level question?

Comment: Thank you for the answers! So we have:
$$||\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}||_{L_2(\partial \Omega)} = ||\nabla v||_{L_2(\partial \Omega)} \leq C_\Omega || \nabla v ||_{W_2^1(\Omega)} \leq C_\Omega ||v||_{W_2^2(\Omega)} ?$$

Comment: First equality should be $\leq$: $\partial v / \partial n$ is pointwise $\leq |\nabla v|$.